# Is it true that subtle body has all five senses?

Tags: body, indriyas

Human body has five senses: hear, see, touch, smell and taste.

It Is well known from Hindu scriptures that every human being has a subtle body.

Does the subtle body has all the five senses?

Comment: See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31709). There are 17 components of the subtle body and the five sense organs are among those components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, actually it is no other than subtle body which consists of senses.

Quoting from [Vivekachudamani](https://www.shastras.com/adi-sankara/vivekachudamani/) of Adi Shankaracharya:

> वागादि पञ्च श्रवणादि पञ्च
>       प्राणादि पञ्चाभ्रमुखानि पञ्च ।
>   बुद्ध्याद्यविद्यापि च कामकर्मणी
>       पुर्यष्टकं सूक्ष्मशरीरमाहुः ॥ ९६॥
>
> 96. The **five organs of action** such as speech, the **five organs of knowledge** such as the ear, the group of five Pranas, the five elements ending with the ether, together with Buddhi and the rest as also Nescience, desire and action - these eight "cities" make up what **is called the subtle body**.

This is also called Linga Sharira which is produced out of the *apañcikṛta bhūta​s*

> 97. Listen - this subtle body, called also the Linga body, is produced out of the elements before their subdividing and combining with each other, is possessed of latent impressions and causes the soul to experience the fruits of its past actions. It is a beginning-less superimposition on the soul brought on by its own ignorance.

Gross body is produced out of *pañcikṛta bhūta​s*.

Panchikaranam is the process of uniting or combining parts of subtle elements forming gross elements. For more study, read [Panchikaranam](https://www.shastras.com/adi-sankara/panchikaranam/) of Adi Shankaracharya. (A Hindi book explaining commentaries on Panchikaranam is available on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/PanchikaranamDr.KameshwarNathMishra))