# Relationship between Jiva and Sukshma Sharira

Tags: advaita, atma, jiva, samsara, jivatman

It is my understanding that the Jiva-Atman is the same as the Atman, it is just this all pervasive consciousness reflected in a body and seemingly trapped in Samsara (correct me if I'm wrong). But I have also heard that it is the Sukshma Sharira that trans-migrates from body to body. Anyone have a simple explanation (from an Advaita Vedantic perspective) as to:

1. What is the relationship between the Jiva-Atman and Sukshma Sharira and  what is it that travels from body to body the Jiva-Atman or the Subtle Body.
2. Is the Sukshma Sharira/Subtle body subject to the senses, gunas, desires etc but the Jiva-Atman not? If the Jiva is not subject to the desires, why does it travel to the next body?

Thank you

Comment: Partially related answer:https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31709/4732. The subtle body is comprised of the sense organs, mind etc.

Comment: I think that the answer by me (linked above) convincingly answers your question from Advaita Vedanta's perspective. Do you need any more clarifications on the relation between Jiva and Sukshma Sarira? Which is not found in that answer?

Comment: The Jiva and the subtle body are the same in Advaita Vedanta. And, this subtle body consists of 17 components among which mind, buddhi, the sense organs are there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does a Soul attach to the Body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body)

Comment: @Rickross If Jiva and Subtle body are the same, does this mean the subtle body/mind is consciousness?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda. Yes this helped a little with my understanding of the 3 bodies thank you. Still a bit confused as to what is it that moves from body to body. The subtle body or Jiva or are they the same. Thank you

Comment: @Kar You can check the "Amrita Tika" found in my answer. That explains that there is hardly any difference between Jiva and the subtle body. But mind is not consciousness.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Bodies_Doctrine Basically there are 3 layer of bodies, gross or visible material body, subtle or mental astral body and last causal or Higher Self's body. Common Humans and animals live in gross earthly body; ghosts, pitras, gods live in subtle mental astral body while yogis or gyanis like avadhutas live in causal or witness body. Jivatman like any common human or animal is a false ego identifying with temporary gross earthly body but controlled & given body by Prakriti(cosmic intellect) based on accumulation of previous births' Karmas stored in sukshma body