# What happens to sukshma sharir after death?

Tags: atma

We leave the gross body behind, the aatman is reincarnated in another life form based on our karma, but what happens to the subtle body? Where does it go after death? What happens to it once we die?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does a Soul attach to the Body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body)

Comment: Sukshma Sarira is not destroyed even after death .. see this - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31709

Comment: Namaste, thanks for the reference. The text says "This Sukshma Sarira leaves the gross body at death and enjoys/suffers at heaven/hell and again obtains (according to Karma) a gross body. This is Jiva ... As long as VAsanAs (desires) exist and the Jiva does not realize the Self, the subtle body exists. Due to the nature of Karma it gets births and deaths again and again.." so how is that different from the Aatman? I would appreciate if you could help 