How vasanas exist even after brain cells are gone?
There are similarities between vasanas and memories. Both store information.
As we know memories does not exist if the brain cells damage but our consciousness still exist.
Assume a person got severe injury to brain and forgot his parents, he is conscious but still cannot recognize his parents. His consciousness does not know who are his parents, so consciousness and memories are not linked to each other.
(Assuming memory and vasanas both are same ) If a person's good and bad activities are all stored in memory which itself not linked to consciousness then how vasanas will be retained across birth?
If vasanas and memories both are different, memories linked to brain and vasanas linked to consciousness then why his consciousness does not identify vasana of his parents and say they are his parents?
Even if the memories are gone, vasanas always exist for consciousness right, then why he is not able to tell that they are his parents from his vasanas with his consciousness?
That person be like let my brain cells damage, I can say these are my parents from my consciousness (i.e. from vasanas in consciousness), but thats not the case here.

Vasanas and Samskaras remain attached to the subtle body of the Jiva. And subtle body remains intact until Moksha. Brain cells etc. are however part of the physical body which get destroyed withe the body .. here is one related answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31709/4732

@Rickross what do u mean intact? The subtle-body arises and vanishes with phenomena.  I think chitta is what remains, but needs a vehicle to express

Subtle body does not get destroyed until Moksha happens @blue_ego

The damage of the physical body of course may lead to a man not to recognize his parents. His memory may fail. However, a man is not just a physical body. He also has a subtle body.

When he gets a new body or abandons an old one, the Jiva, the lord of
the body, moves, carrying them (the mind and the senses) with him, as
the world carries smells from their seats (in flowers and the like).

Gita 15.8
The vasanas are not the same as memory. Nor do vasanas store information. Vasanas affect the mind in the subtle body. Vasanas leave imprints on the mind. These imprints are called samskaras. So after rebirth these samskaras affect a man's behavior in the new birth.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Good question now understand Mr/Miss.
When you were born everyone teaches you how to speak, how to walk, who is your parents, as these all are information but no one teaches you to get hungry it is just part of body, no one teaches you to sleep and still you are doing it because it is the default thing yes but they taught you if you feel hungry go and eat McD's meal.
Answer is vasna is default thing noone is above
Infect one day I was thinking the greatest god shiva and vishnu. One who are beyond anything even we define BEYONDNESS in comparison with them. They are not as vishnu take mohini avtar roop at that time one child get's birth from shiva some scriptures mentions it whose name is Lord Ayyappa
Shiva is the one who meditate so even time get's stop he is beyond time. if he can not stop the vasna(here vasna is not using in bad meaning) so who are you and me. Only way is to control nothing else gonna work.
I'm bad on stack so please ignore my format and English too:)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
